# How can I simplify this?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, text-formatting

Can you help me simplify this script?

This works but I think that there is a easier way to do it, but I can't find it.

The file:

```
Car Brand:Mercedes | Country:Germany | Car Model:300 SL | Year:04-1960
Car Brand:Lamborghini | Country:Italy | Car Model:Miura | Year:10-1970
Car Brand:Aston Martin | Country:UK | Car Model:DBS | Year:12-1965
Car Brand:Ford | Country:United States of America | Car Model:GT40 | Year:09-1966
```

Output:

```
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

1,2,3,4 is the number of the line; 61, 52, 56, 55 (current year - year, ignoring the month), xxx insurance company (always the same, this part stopped working)

Script:

```
line=$(awk '{print NR}' file.txt)
brand=$(sed 's/.*Brand:\(.*\) | Country.*/\1/' file.txt)
country=$(sed 's/.*Country:\(.*\) | Year.*/\1/' file.txt)
sed 's/.*Year:\(.*\) | Car.*/\1/; s/^...//' file.txt > cars.txt
age=$(awk -v age="$(date +%Y)" '{print age - $1}' cars.txt)
model=$(sed 's/.*Model:\(.*\)*/\1/' file.txt)
echo "$(paste <(echo "$line") <(echo "$brand") <(echo "$country") <(echo "$age") <(echo "$model") -d ':')" > cars.txt
# sed -i 's/$/:xxx/' cars.txt
cat cars.txt
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -v yr="$(date +'%Y') " -F' *[:|-] *' -v OFS=':' '{print NR, $2, $4, $6, yr-$9, "xxx"}' file
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

The above assumes that `:`, `|`, and `-` can only appear in the locations shown in your example. If a `-` can appear in a brand name (e.g. `Mercedes-Benz`) or elsewhere in the input then tweak the above to this:

```
awk -v yr=$(date +%Y) -F' *[:|] *' -v OFS=':' '{sub(/.*-/,"",$8); print NR, $2, $4, $6, yr-$8, "xxx"}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
Car Brand:Mercedes-Benz | Country:Germany | Car Model:300 SL | Year:04-1960
Car Brand:Lamborghini | Country:Italy | Car Model:Miura | Year:10-1970
Car Brand:Aston Martin | Country:UK | Car Model:DBS | Year:12-1965
Car Brand:Ford | Country:United States of America | Car Model:GT40 | Year:09-1966
```

```
$ awk -v yr=$(date +%Y) -F' *[:|] *' -v OFS=':' '{sub(/.*-/,"",$8); print NR, $2, $4, $6, yr-$8, "xxx"}' file
1:Mercedes-Benz:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

If there's any `:` or `|` that can be present other than where you've shown then fix your example to be more truly representative of your real data.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk and appropriate field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS)

```
gawk -F '|' -v OFS=: -v yr="$(date +%Y)" '
{ 
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
    gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/, "", $i)
    sub(/.*:/, "", $i)
    if (i==NF) {
      sub(/[^-]+/, "", $i)
      $i += yr
    }
  }
  print NR, $0, "xxx"
}
' file
```

Output:

```
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

Comment: If you changed `\s` to `[[:space:]]` then it would behave the same in every POSIX awk and no longer be GNU-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
BEGIN {
        # Initialize the input field separator to a
        # pattern matching the literal string " | "
        # (space-pipe-space).  Set the output field
        # separator to a colon.
        FS  = " [|] "; OFS = ":"

        # Pick out the current year.
        # (This bit is not standard awk.)
        year = strftime("%Y")
}

{
        # Go through the fields of the current line, one
        # by one, and remove the bit before the (first)
        # colon in each. We don't touch the last field
        # yet.
        for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) sub("[^:]*:","",$i)

        # For the last field, remove everything but the
        # last four characters. Subtract this from the
        # current year.
        $NF = year - substr($NF,length($NF)-3)

        # Print the resulting line, preceded by the input
        # line number and a colon. Also put ":xxx" at the
        # end.
        printf "%d:%s:xxx\n", NR, $0
}
```

Again, with no comments,

```c
BEGIN {
        FS  = " [|] "; OFS = ":"
        year = strftime("%Y")
}

{
        for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) sub("[^:]*:","",$i)
        $NF = year - substr($NF,length($NF)-3)
        printf "%d:%s:xxx\n", NR, $0
}
```

The `awk` code above treats each line in the input file as a set of field separated by  `|`  (space-pipe-space).

The main block starts by looping over each field (except for the last) and removes everything up to the (first) colon in each.

The last field (`$NF`) is modified to be the current year minus whatever number the last four characters of the field forms.  The current year is had via `strftime()`.  This function is not a standard `awk` function, but GNU `awk`, `mawk`, and the native `awk` on OpenBSD supports it.

Once all the fields have been appropriately modified, the line is printed with the extra data prepended (the line number) and appended (the `xxx` string).

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script file
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

Testing single line variant:

```
$ awk -F ' [|] ' -v OFS=: 'BEGIN {y=strftime("%Y")} {for(i=1;i<NF;++i)sub("[^:]*:","",$i);$NF=y-substr($NF,length($NF)-3);printf "%d:%s:xxx\n",NR,$0}' file
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to convert from (the default) delimited key-value pair ("dkvp") format to "csvlite" (or "csv"):

```
$ cat file
Car Brand:Mercedes | Country:Germany | Car Model:300 SL | Year:04-1960
Car Brand:Lamborghini | Country:Italy | Car Model:Miura | Year:10-1970
Car Brand:Aston Martin | Country:UK | Car Model:DBS | Year:12-1965
Car Brand:Ford | Country:United States of America | Car Model:GT40 | Year:09-1966
```

then

```
$ mlr --ifs ' | ' --ips ':' --ocsvlite --ofs ':' \
    put '$Item = NR; $Year = strftime(strptime($Year,"%m-%Y"),"%y"); ${Insurance Co} = "xxx"' \
    then reorder -f Item file
Item:Car Brand:Country:Car Model:Year:Insurance Co
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:60:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:70:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:65:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:66:xxx
```

Add `--headerless-csv-output` if you don't want the CSV header.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "[:|]" '{print NR":"$2":"$4":"$6":",strftime("%Y-%m-%d")-substr($NF,4)":xxx"}'  filename
```

output

```
1:Mercedes:Germany:300 SL:61:xxx
2:Lamborghini:Italy:Miura:51:xxx
3:Aston Martin:UK:DBS:56:xxx
4:Ford:United States of America:GT40:55:xxx
```